# Listing Awards on CV as a Group?

Tags: cv, awards

I work in a field where a group of about 20 people all have a different role on a project.  When a project wins an award in this field, they typically do not list people individually.  How can I put awards like this on my CV?

Answer (score 6):

Same as you would a normal in-line item, only you'd mention at the end that you were a member of a group name. You can also mention role.

- John Doe Award of Excellence, Annual Competition of Cooking Tasty Foods in Somewhere, AA on 1 Jan 1999, as head chef of Team Mashed Potatoes

Comment: Let's say you weren't head chef, but rather chief bottle washer (or some other lowly position).  Would you still format this in the same way?

Comment: @anorton You can say "Team Member" if you wish.

Comment: Should you add your title? Project X award for best box of the year, for Acme Co. Designer 2014.

Comment: Yes, but you should mention that you are a designer, so "Acme Co., as a Designer." And I would normally split the year off to where the award is mentioned